# Git log, showing file changes

Tags: git, logging

How do I perform a git log for a file showing the changes to the file in a diff like manner?

e.g

```
git log Foo/Bar.config
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
git log -p -- afile
```

From the [git log man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
-p
-u
--patch
```

> Generate patch (see [section on generating patches](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_generating_patches_with_-p)).